# Tabulator - exclusive header filters - how?

Tags: tabulator

I wrote and support a little web app for our local animal shelter to help volunteers locate dogs. I chose Tabulator because it had great features and was easy to use and have been very happy with my choice. For the first version of the app I used external input fields to search and manually did all the wiring to support live search.

Now I am working on v2 and am trying to use header filters. My problem is that the filters need to be exclusive, that is, using filter1 clears/disables filters 2 and 3, using filter2 clears/disables 1 and 3, and so on. With the external search fields I used focus() events to do this. When I try using jQuery on(focus) delegates to do the same with header filters and for example table.setHeaderFilterValue("field1", "") it does not work; the event triggers but the input box never gets the focus so I cannot type in it. I've tried different events like click; but nothing I've tried works properly.

I've studied the docs and struggled with this for several hours. I've considered hooking dataFiltering() and eliminating the filters I don't want, but I'm not sure how to identify the filter that I want to keep, and there is still the matter of the text in the fields to be dealt with. I'm sure it doesn't help that front-end work is not my area of expertise, though so far I've managed well enough. Is there a simple or normal way to do this that I'm just not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I found a way to do exclusive filtering with header filters with a single event callback:

```
        \$(document).on("focus", ".tabulator-col input[type=search]", function() {
            var hfNames = ["name", "anum", "kennel"];
            var fieldName = \$(this).closest(".tabulator-col")[0].getAttribute("tabulator-field");
            hfNames.map(function(hfN) { if (hfN != fieldName) table.setHeaderFilterValue(hfN, "") });
        });
```

The three hfNames are the field names of the columns with filtering on. Yes, I could have derived them dynamically, but it didn't seem worth it for a small app like this.

As I suspected, the key was simply a better knowledge of JQuery.